# SecretClient - get secret from azure KeyVault

Tags: azure, client, storage, azure-keyvault, secret-key

I want to get the value of a secret in keyvault in Azure,
I saw that I can create a SecretClient like this: `var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret));`

how do I know the value to give the constructor? where can I found the clientId, ClientSecret and the kvUri?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an application for access first when using ClientSecretCredential.

Navigate to Azure Active Directory -> App registrations -> New registration

`tenantId` and `clientId` are in the "Overview" :

[image]

`clientSecret` is in "Certificates & secrets":

[image]

**Note:** After creating the application, you must add access policy in key vault for the application.

[image]